# How to lookup thread context in custom log4j2 jsonlayout plugin

Tags: java, log4j2

I have implemented the following plugin to create custom Json layout for log4j logs. I am not sure how I can implement the context lookup in the Plugin. For example, the application puts certain keys in MDC and with the below configuration in log4j.xml, it must be written in logs.

```
<KeyValuePair key="customerId" value="$${customerId}" />.
```

**Plugin**

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomJsonLayout", category = "Core", elementType = "layout", printObject = true)
public class CustomJsonLayout extends AbstractStringLayout {
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

CustomJsonLayout(Charset charset) {
    super(charset);
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(LogEvent.class, new LogEventSerializer());
    module.addSerializer(ReadOnlyStringMap.class, new ContextDataSerializer() {
    });
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
}

@Override
public String toSerializable(LogEvent logEvent) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(logEvent);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private static class LogEventSerializer extends StdSerializer<LogEvent> {
    LogEventSerializer() {
        super(LogEvent.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LogEvent value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(value.getTimeMillis()));

        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("timestamp", date);
        gen.writeStringField("component", MicroService.getAppName());
        gen.writeStringField("severity", value.getLevel().name());
        gen.writeObjectField("msg", value.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());
        gen.writeEndObject();
        gen.writeRaw("\n");
    }
}

@PluginBuilderFactory
public static <B extends Builder<B>> B newBuilder() {
    return new Builder<B>().asBuilder();
}

public static class Builder<B extends Builder<B>> extends org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout.Builder<B> implements org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Builder<CustomJsonLayout> {
    Builder() {
        this.setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    public CustomJsonLayout build() {
        return new CustomJsonLayout(this.getCharset());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you have tried using the lookup and it is failing? I ask because I would expect the lookup to be resolved /before/ the parameters are passed into your logic.

Comment: No, I was asking how to implement the `KeyValuePair` in `JsonLayout`

Comment: Have you looked at the [source for JsonLayout](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=logging-log4j2.git;a=blob_plain;f=log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/JsonLayout.java;hb=bf42c2f17ef53342edc6e707f960569aae347b65)? Also, you might consider extending `JsonLayout` or at least using its code as a template for your own.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing, have you found a solution?